# get_term_link() not working after installing multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

`get_term_link()` inserts `/blog/` in between the permalink.

It was giving the correct permalink before I installed multi-site.

After installing `multi-site` this is not working. Can you help me to find out the issue?